# SSIS BLOBTempStorage Failed to retrieve long data for column

Tags: ssis

We are running an SSIS package that uses a data flow task to copy data from a source to destination.  We have one table that contains a text datatype.  For this table we ran into issues in the past, so we utilized the BLOBTempStoragePath and BufferTempStoragePath properties to offload some temporary storage from the C drive to an H drive.

The problem we are running into is that we are running out of space on the H drive now when this job runs.  The odd thing is that the entire database is around 12 GB in size.  When the job runs we usually have around 40 GB available on the H drive.  We also tried setting the Rows per batch and Maximum insert commit size for the data flow destination (OLEDB Destination) in hopes that it would consume less disk space.

[image: Dataflow destination settings]

I hate to have to increase the size of this drive further for this one process that runs on a nightly basis.  Is anyone aware of any settings that would allow this package to maybe run a bit slower, but consume less disk space?

Edit:
The data flow task is simple a source and destination.  There aren't any transforms.  Here is an image:

[image]

Comment: Interesting. Can you confirm that the used space after package execution, assuming successful, is the same as space preceding execution? I always *assumed* temp files were cleaned up but never verified. Oh, a thought just occurred to me - could you post a screenshot of what you're doing within the data flow - my brain is trying to figure out how you could be consuming so much disk space

Comment: I have noticed some temporary files linger.  The directory currently consumes about 110 MB.  Prior to the package running and after it fails, there is around 45 GB free on the drive.

Comment: Please describe the problems. There should not be issues ingesting textual data.